risc-v-simple is not booting up once i add cache
I want to run the Simics RISC-V-simple machine while modeling caches.
I would also like to see the how is cache being implemented on the board cause after running the below commands on the console I did not find any connections to another thing on the board
  new-simple-cache-tool name = cachetool -connect-all
(cachetool.add-l2-cache name = l2 line-size = 64 sets = 1024 ways = 20
 -prefetch-adjacent prefetch-additional = 4)

with this i expected the RISC-V machine to continue as it it but i face this error:


More context is needed for the error. This seems like the tail end of an assert of some kind, and the context complaint could be a follow-on error from the assert. It is not the actual error, just a symptom.

I tested this myself.  Seems that the simple-cache-tool currently does not work for the RISC-V target which is a bit of a bummer.  It expects X86-type memory accesses.

Please refer the file targets\workshop-01\005-auto-cache-analysis.simics
Review how to add cache to the system:
run-command-file "%script%/add-cache-hierarchy.include" system=$system
Then review this file: add-cache-hierarchy.include
See how the new-simple-cache-tool is used and cache is added.
I would recommend following similar steps and adding the cache_sim under the "board"

Ok sir,
great will try that out during summer vac.
